# Como usar "for" para trabalhar com dados em um array cujo a quantidade de dados variados é desconhecida?

Tags: php, json, array, for, foreach

Tenho a seguinte variável JSON resultante de uma consulta em php:

```
$json_string = '[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Jogos para PC",
    "products": [
      {
        "id": 34,
        "name": "Grand Theft Auto V"
      },
      {
        "id": 59,
        "name": "Bloodstained Ritual of the Night"
      },
      {
        "id": 60,
        "name": "F1 2019 - Anniversary Edition"
      },
      {
        "id": 62,
        "name": "PLAYERUNKNOWN\'S BATTLEGROUNDS"
      },
      {
        "id": 64,
        "name": "Batman: Arkham Knight"
      }
    ],
    "tags": []
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Jogos Mobile",
    "products": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Clash of Clãs"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Mobile Legends"
      }
    ],
    "tags": []
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "PlayStation Store",
    "products": [
      {
        "id": 39,
        "name": "PSN Gift Card - R$ 30,00"
      },
      {
        "id": 40,
        "name": "PSN Gift Card - R$ 60,00"
      }
    ],
    "tags": []
  }
]';
```

Utilizo o comando `$array = json_decode($json_string);` para trabalhar a seguir com o seguinte código:

```
$array = json_decode($json_string);
foreach ($array as $value)
    {
        for ($row = 0; $row < 5; $row++) {
        echo $value->products[($row)]->name .' - ID: '. $value->products[($row)]->id .'<br>';
    }
}
```

Isso me retorna os nomes dos jogos da seguinte maneira:

```
Grand Theft Auto V - ID: 34<br>
Bloodstained Ritual of the Night - ID: 59<br>
F1 2019 - Anniversary Edition - ID: 60<br>
PLAYERUNKNOWN'S BATTLEGROUNDS - ID: 62<br>
Batman: Arkham Knight - ID: 64<br>
Clash of Clãs - ID: 3<br>
Mobile Legends - ID: 4<br>
```

Utilizei `$row < 5` pois sei que a maior quantidade de jogos em uma das listas é 5, dessa forma todos aparecem, o problema é quando a lista tem menos de 5 jogos pois o PHP retorna um erro:

[image: erro apresentado com o código atual]

Portanto, considerando que não soubesse a quantidade de jogos em cada um dos conjuntos, qual seria a maneira correta de listar todos os jogos do *array*?

Comment: Não precisa ser exatamente com 'for', esta foi a maneira mais próxima de chegar onde preciso, por isso utilizei na pergunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode sempre usar o [`count()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.count.php) para obter o tamanho da array.

---

Portanto, se está usando `$value->products[($row)]`, pode usar o `count($value->products)` para obter quantos existem.

```
for ($row = 0; $row < count($value->products); $row++) {
    echo $value->products[($row)]->name .' - ID: '. $value->products[($row)]->id .'<br>';
}
```

---

Você também pode usar o `foreach`, que foi o mesmo que já usou anteriormente (você usou `foreach ($array as $value)` antes, portanto já sabe como isto funciona).

```
foreach ($value->products as $product) {
    echo $product->name .' - ID: '. $product->id .'<br>';
}
```

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado pela resposta

Answer (score 3):

O valor da chave `products` também é um array, [pois é delimitado por `[` e `]`](https://www.json.org/json-en.html):

```
"products": [
    ... etc
]
```

Sendo assim, basta percorrê-lo com `foreach` também:

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
    foreach ($value->products as $product) {
        echo $product->name .' - ID: '. $product->id .'<br>';
    }
}
```

Saída:

```
Grand Theft Auto V - ID: 34<br>
Bloodstained Ritual of the Night - ID: 59<br>
F1 2019 - Anniversary Edition - ID: 60<br>
PLAYERUNKNOWN'S BATTLEGROUNDS - ID: 62<br>
Batman: Arkham Knight - ID: 64<br>
Clash of Clãs - ID: 3<br>
Mobile Legends - ID: 4<br>
PSN Gift Card - R$ 30,00 - ID: 39<br>
PSN Gift Card - R$ 60,00 - ID: 40<br>
```

Comment: não havia pensado em utilizar um foreach dentro do outro, gostei da alternativa e também funcionou perfeitamente. muito obrigado!